# Front-end searching: Automatically redirect when only 1 result

Tags: search

When performing a search on the front-end, is it possible to have two different behaviors, depending on the number of results?

- With more than one result, show the normal "results" page.
- With only a single result, **automatically redirect to that entry page.**

Comment: I've reworded the question based on what I believe you are after... Please feel free to roll it back (or edit further) if I am mistaken!

Comment: Ahhh... thanks for the edit / translation @Lindsey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redirecting](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/redirect) to the first result is simple...

```
{% if results|length == 1 %}
    {% redirect results[0].url %}
{% endif %}
```